# Where can i find an open source iOS 5 templates?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, springboard

To be more specific, i am looking for a 'springboard' template. I have seen a couple of GitHub projects which allow creating similar controls in less time, but none for the springboard( Old Facebook type app).Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be found here:[Cocoa Controls](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=springboard)

There you'll find some templates to choose from under the appropriate licenses for your purpose.